# IntelliSense does not format properly XML Summaries in C#

Tags: c#, intellisense

I did a few summeries in different languages like Cpp and C and IntelliSense categorizes params and return with a standard formatting.

In C# I have the following code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates
    /// <param name="r">radius</param>
    /// <param name="theta">angle</param>
    /// <returns>cartesian coordinates</returns>
    /// </summary>
    public Vector3 ToCartesian() { 
        return new Vector3(r * Mathf.Cos(theta), r * Mathf.Sin(theta), 0);
    }
```

but IntelliSense just shows this:

[image]

Is there any ways to format this that it does more look like this (from Cpp):

[image]

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @marcwellman VS Code of course.

Comment: The method doesn't have any parameters?

Comment: @CharlesMager Ah, sorry I recreated this and forgot to add the params, but the problem still exists with parameters. The return doesnt get formatted correctly as well and as you see there is a return value

Comment: Did you install the C# Extension, which also gives you more Intellisense settings?

Comment: @marcwellman I do have the C# extension from microsoft installed. For example it shows me compiler errors in line and variable references. So, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are not using the correct format.

Please, try by closing summary before to start the param's section.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e"></param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
```

Comment: Wow, i think, you nailed it :-)